# Sums of binomials with increasing powers

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am curious if there is a way to simplify the following:

\begin{align}
& 1+a+(a+b)^2+(a+b)^3+\cdots+(a+b)^n \\[8pt]
= {} &1+a+\sum_{k=0}^2  {2 \choose k} a^kb^{2-k} +\sum_{k=0}^3 {3 \choose k}a^kb^{3-k}+\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: Well, it's basically a geometric series.  Did you mean that first $1$ to be a $b$?  But even if it is a $1$, you can just sum the majority of the terms as  a Geometric series.

Comment: the first term is a 1 @lulu

Comment: Ok, so then just sum $(a+b)^2+\cdots +(a+b)^n$ as a [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and add $1+a$ to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$S=1+(a+b)+(a+b)^2 + \dots + (a+b)^n$$
and the required is $S-b$, now
$$S(a+b)=(a+b)+(a+b)^2 + \dots + (a+b)^n+(a+b)^{n+1}$$
$$S(a+b)-S=(a+b)^{n+1}-1 \iff S=\frac{(a+b)^{n+1}-1}{a+b-1}$$
So the required is 
$$\frac{(a+b)^{n+1}-1}{a+b-1}-b$$